# Are socket file descriptors > FD_SETSIZE valid on OS X?

Tags: macos, sockets, file-descriptor

On OS X, we're finding that calls to ::socket(...) can sometimes return a file descriptor that is greater than FD_SETSIZE. According to the docs for ::socket(...) this is a successful request, as only return values of -1 indicate failure. However, throughout our codebase – before using the descriptor – we're testing that it's within the range 0 to FD_SETSIZE inclusive.

Is this the correct thing to be doing, or can we safely go ahead and use the sockets whose descriptors are greater than FD_SETSIZE?

The reason this is happening is is because we're calling ::setrlimit(...) with the RLIMIT_NOFILE flag to up the maximum number of file descriptors. We need to do this because our application has to keep a large number of files open simultaneously. However, this value is obtained via a call to sysctl(...) with the KERN_MAXFILESPERPROC flag and set at run-time, whereas FD_SETSIZE is a compile-time setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use socket descriptors which have a value which is greater than `FD_SETSIZE`, just not with an `fd_set`.